# AutoCompleteTextView doesn't recognize spaces

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I'm using an AutoCompleteTextView in my Android application, which is loaded with items like this one:

"Smoky chinchilla rat - Abrocoma cinerea"

Which are common names and scientific names of many animals...

Now, if I type "smo" is fine, the item above is shown nicely, the problem starts when I type things like "abrocoma " (note the space)... the instant I type the space after "abrocoma" the selections dissapear, as if the sequence "abrocoma " doesn't appear in the line...

The above is only true for spaces after the first word... If I type "smoky " is fine...

More, if I type "smoky chinchilla rat - abrocoma " it still shows the dropdown just fine, the only problem is when I start with any word but the first.

I don't know if this is an error of the AutoCompleteTextView or my code.

Any direction is appreciated.

Greetings

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE!!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12854336/autocompletetextview-backed-by-cursorloader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you taken a look at [this](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/3abb0ddb14690e60?pli=1) post? The user was having a similar issue, and he wrote is own derivation:

> I just ran into a similar problem and wrote a simple multi word 
>   derivation. It defaults to a "," separator but you can set it whatever
>   you like using the "setSeparator" method.